# Ideals by the polynomial with "shifted" variables like g(x,y,z,) g(y,z,u), g(z, u,v)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ideals

Are there any results related to properties of an ideal $I$ in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ generated by the polynomials  $g(x_1,\ldots, x_m),\, g(x_2,\ldots, x_{m+1}), \ldots, g(x_{1+{n-m}},\ldots , x_{n})$?  Here $m \leq n$, $g$ is a polynomial of $m$ variables and $k$ is any field of characteristic zero, not necessarily algebraically closed.

The aim is to find conditions on $g$ under which there is a linear polynomial $L \in k[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$ which vanishes on $V(I) \subset K$ where $K$ is the algebraic closure of $k$.

I have been experimenting with Hilbert Nullstellensatz, but I could not see any elegant "killing" solution. It amounts to equating the polynomial coefficients  arising from the equation  of the form $L^r = h_0g_0 + \ldots + h_{n-m}g_{n-m}$ where $g_i(x_1,\ldots, x_n) := g(x_{1+i}, \ldots, x_{m+i})$ are known polynomials, whereas $L$ and $h_i$ are polynomials and $r$ is a natural number whose existence we need to check.

Why I want to know it at all? I will explain it in a separate comment below.

Comment: Hi! I think that in order to get any answer, you should be more specific. What properties are you looking for? Or maybe why are you looking for them?

Comment: @IgorSikora, Hi, Igor, thanks a lot for your hints. I have edited the question. All in all, I'm interested in closed from solutions of nonlinear algebraic difference equations.  Have had 2 pubs about it; the last one: [link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S074771711930135X).  
Now I digress to a recurrence equation but considering not just a polynomial solution but a more general function which is solutions for some linear recurrence equation. I believe that in "many cases" the order of alternative linear recurrence does not exceed the order of the original nonlinear one.